# Ambient Occlusion Baking has no shading

Tags: texture-baking

Whenever I try to bake my character model with an ambient occlusion, I don't get the shading effect that I want (take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYBPXTful2g&t=690s)). So can someone help me achieve this effect with the ambient occlusion? Here's are pictures, am I doing anything wrong?[image: With Wireframe][image: Without Wireframe]

Comment: Would you mind [uploading](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) your file? I have tried several possible problems but none of them resembled yours (changind environment lighting had something close)

Comment: can  you show how you set AO ? and a rendered image with AO?